# Disable Start-Up Applications

Tags: server, startup, startup-applications

I followed [this tutorial on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jw3jlemIrd0) to disable start-up applications in Ubuntu Sever 13.10. 
What happened is all unchecked apps are being checked again when I close then open the box! What should I do to keep them unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

sysv-rc-conf is the tool you want:

```
sudo apt-get install sysv-rc-conf
```

You have to run it as root:

```
sudo sysv-rc-conf
```

then use the arrow keys to navigate, spacebar to select, q to quit. Be sure you know what you are doing.

PS: the video you posted is for ubuntu desktop (unity). You didn't install X on your server, just for that, right?

Comment: Thanks, but this conf is for services, I'm already done with it. Now I locking for disabling unnecessary start-up applications